# Shopify slick carousel with dynamic image blocks

Tags: javascript, shopify, carousel, liquid, slick.js

I am trying to implement a slick carousel in the home page. The slides for the carousel are added as blocks in the slider section. I have already added the required css, js and jquery cdn in my theme.liquid file. In the customize option for shopify, I can now add dynamic images for the slideshow but the carousel or the images are not showing up on the website.

Here's my theme.liquid file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}">
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
  
  <!--css file-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'custom.css' | asset_url }}" type="text/css" media="print" onload="this.media='all';onLoadStylesheet()">
  
  <!--slick css?-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

  {{ content_for_header }}
</head>

<body>
  {% section 'header' %}

  <main role="main">
    {{ content_for_layout }}
  </main>

  <!--slick jquery and js-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my slider.liquid file:

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="image-container">
        {% for slide in settings.blocks %}
            <div class="image-title">
                {{ slide.slide_title }}
            </div>

            <div class="slider-image">
                <img src="{{ slide.slide_img | img_url: 'grande' }}">
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class="slider-next">Next</div>
    <div class="slider-prev">Prev</div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.slider-container').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 5,
      nextArrow:$('.slider-next'),
      prevArrow:$('.slider-prev'),
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: false
  
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  </script>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Slideshow",
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "slideshow",
  "max_blocks": 5,
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Slideshow"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
     {
       "name": "Slide",
       "type": "slide",
       "settings": [
         {
           "type": "image_picker",
           "id": "slide_image",
           "label": "Image"
         }, 
         {
            "type": "text",
            "id":"slide_title",
            "label":"Title"
         }
       ]
     }
   ],
  "presets": [
     {
       "name": "Slideshow",
       "settings": {
          "title": "Slideshow"
        },
       "blocks": [
         {
           "type": "slide"
         },
         {
           "type": "slide"
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

my index.liquid file:

```
{{ content_for_index }}

{% section 'slider' %}
```

Comment: Can you share the preview link?

Comment: I can not really share the link, but can you tell me if I did it correct by adding the cdn files in theme.liquid and then having the script function and schema in the slider.liquid file?

Comment: There are two options - slick carousel wasnt imported properly and it doesnt initialize or there is an error or you haven't put any images yet or grande is wrong image size but then carousel works. Check console to see if there are any errors. Try to find images in generated HTML

Comment: I think you need to change the order of code, you add the slick library into the footer and slick slider code above it. this is the issue in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**Image id is different from Schema image id**
```

---- This slider is working ----

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="image-container Pre_slide">
        {% for block in section.blocks %}
            <div class="image-title">
                {{ block.settings.slide_title }}
            </div>

            <div class="slider-image">
                <img src="{{ block.settings.slide_image | img_url: 'master' }}">
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class="slider-next">Next</div>
    <div class="slider-prev">Prev</div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.Pre_slide').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      nextArrow:$('.slider-next'),
      prevArrow:$('.slider-prev'),
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: false
  
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  </script>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Slideshow",
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "slideshow",
  "max_blocks": 5,
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Slideshow"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
     {
       "name": "Slide",
       "type": "slide",
       "settings": [
         {
           "type": "image_picker",
           "id": "slide_image",
           "label": "Image"
         }, 
         {
            "type": "text",
            "id":"slide_title",
            "label":"Title"
         }
       ]
     }
   ],
   "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Custom Slider"
    }
  ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: missing arrows? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>`